# How to pass variables from page to page in JSP?

Tags: jsp

What i want to do is pass a variable from one page to another.

This is what I have:

```
<html>
<%@include file="sqlBasic.jsp"%>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
Please fix the following error(s):<br>
<%=msg%>

     <%@ include file="incTail.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<%@include file="sqlBasic.jsp"%>` contains the declaration `String msg="";` Another page changes the variable msg to something else. But when it prints its just an empty string. How can i pass the changed variable of msg to be displayed on this page?

Comment: you'd use a session. you do NOT want to re-write that file dynamically to change its value, because multiple users of the site will all be stomping on each other with their custom values.

Comment: I tried `session.setAttribute("msg", msg);`  and `session.getAttribute("msg");`It still didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because in the same file you are both setting and retrieving, i.e. setting before you retrieve and thus setting the session var back to null. The setting and retrieving should be in different files that don't include each other, Or the setting should be enclosed in an if-statement to prevent resetting when you don't want it to.

```
String msg = (String)session.getAttribute("msg");
if(msg == null)
{
   //when null, do something, possibly set msg to a default value.
   msg = "default value";
   session.setAttribute("msg", msg);
}
```